# Convert rows of a matrix to vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I have a matrix lets say:

```
A=[1 2 1; 5 6 7; 7 8 9]
```

and I want to extract its rows in the following format:

```
x_1=[1 2 1] x_2=[5 6 7] x_3=[7 8 9]
```

I want to know how I can write `x_1` , `x_2`, `x_3`. I know how to extract the rows but I don't know how to make my `x_1`, `x_2` and `x_3`. **I want this to be automatic**, because my real matrix has a very large size and I don't want to make `x_1 x_2 .. x_100` by hand.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use A(1,:), A(2,:), A(3,:) instead of x_1, x_2 and x_3?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Because I want to manipulate the new set of vectors.
Actually my question is how to reproduce x_1 ... x_100 in Mat-lab automatically. x_1 means x with 1 next to it.

Comment: If it was helpful I wouldn't mind you upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Because I want to manipulate the new set of vectors. Actually my question is how to reproduce x_1 ... x_100 in Mat-lab automatically. x_1 means x with 1 next to it.

Comment: @user3689502: Using consecutive variable names (`x_1...x_100` is a really bad idea. I would try to use the matrix directly, if this is not possible convert it to a cell using mat2cell. Then you can use `x{1}...x{100}`. This simplifies the code.

Comment: You should expand on the problem and let us know what you are trying to do, maybe in a different question. I think you may be approaching the problem in the wrong way as @TommyIvarsson said. Matlab is designed to very easily access row and column vectors through `x(:, 1)` style commands.

Comment: I'm with @TommyIvarsson and @Ben. I can literally think of no situation in which it would be better to do what the OP is proposing than simply copy the original matrix `x = A` and then access the rows as `x(1,:)`, `x(2,:)`, etc. It certainly makes looping over the rows more difficult to have to type in `x_1`, `x_2` and so on. I would appreciate hearing from the OP why this is really necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
m = size(A,1);

for i=1:m
    % set the variable name
    varName = sprintf('x_%d',i);

    % create and assign the variable in the base workspace
    assignin('base',varName,A(i,:));
end
```

The code iterates through every row of **A**, creates the variable name (as per your format) and then assigns a variable in the MATLAB base workspace ('base') with its data being the ith row of **A**.

If doing this from a function, rather than using 'base' use 'caller' to indicate that the variables should be created in the workspace of the function.